# I was wondering what the conversion would be for this algebra πA,D (R ⋈ σB=8 (S))

Tags: relational-algebra

The exercise question asks:

> Consider a relation *R(A, B, C)* and *S(A, B, D)* containing the
>   following tuples:
>
> ```
> A  B  C          A  B  D
> -------          -------
> 6  8  7          5  8  7
> 6  6  7          6  6  7
> 7  8  6          6  8  6
> ```
>
> What to be produced from the expression
>   π<sub>*A,D*</sub>(R⋈σ<sub>*B=8*</sub> (S))

And gives the answer as:

> ```
> A  D
> ----
> 6  6
> ```

Why is this?

I understand that pi is the projection so it will only output tables A and D. First thing I don't understand is why is it not AAD in the new table as there are 2 A's and Second thing is I don't understand what the selection criteria means.

Comment: If you arrive at a different answer, can you include in the question how you are doing so? That will make it easier to see which step needs more explaining.

Comment: Hi. I guess you mean "output *attributes* A and D". However the rest of your final paragraph is unclear. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show how you are evaluting each operator/subexpression. Give a reference to the *definitions* of the version of the relational algebra that you were given. Show how you are applying them. There are many different variations on what a relation is & what exactly the operators do. The definition of ⋈ will *not* say there are 2 As in its output. PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

Selection B=8 from S will give

```
A B D 
5 8 7 
6 8 6
```

Join with R will give

```
A B C D
6 8  7 6
```

since A=6 and B=8  in R table(1st row) and resulting S table(2nd row)

From the projection you will see the answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's work from the inside out. First, consider σ<sub>*B=8*</sub> (S). This is a selection. We use `S` as our source but we only allow through tuples that match the `B=8` condition. So lets label this new relation *T(A, B, D)*:

```
A  B  D
-------
5  8  7
6  8  6
```

The `6,6,7` tuple didn't get selected since its `B` value doesn't equal `8`.

---

Now lets consider R⋈T. This is a natural join between my above `T` tuple and `R`. Natural join is based on all columns with the same name being used to join the relations. We don't get two `A`s or `B`s in this result because a) they're always equal, and b) tuple elements are distinguished by name so you cannot have multiple elements with the same name. So, we produce *U(A,B,C,D)*:

```
A  B  C  D
----------
6  8  7  6
```

(Because only tuple `(6,8,7)` from `R` and `(6,8,6)` from `T` have matching `A` and `B` values).

Finally, we project to only retain `A` and `D` from `U`. Hopefully I don't have to explain that.